# Bluetooth/wifi receiving information

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, wifi, message

I want to design a iPhone app that can receive data for example a name and number from another bluetooth/wifi device i.e. a data controller.

I have designed an app that can content iPhone to iPhone and send message to each other using GameKit but can't workout how or if it can be done from another machine.

It can be sent through bluetooth or local WiFi.

I look forward to hearing your views on this.

Answer (score 0):

The device has be MFi compatible , you will have to join the [apple MFi program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) to get more information. Once the non-iOS device is MFi complaint your iOS app on can talk to the device.